# Role expire in drupal 7 issue

Tags: 7

I have installed [Role Expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_expire) module but how can I set its expire date?

Can anybody please help me because I don't get any clue to write expire date for a particular role?

Comment: have you check this..

Answer (score 3):

From admin, when create users and assign roles i.e. `admin/people/create`, there is a textbox open where admin can insert the expiry date.

[image]

Comment: Yes @Nishant, I had mentioned expiry date, but after expiry date that particular user with custom role assigned by me can login as authenticated user. But I want to restrict the user to login again after expiry date. Is there a way to handle authenticated user role so it will not automatically assigns to every user?